# How to validate canonical name (common name, cn) against certificate subject?

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, x509certificate

In C#, I create an SSL connection to a server like this:

```
var hostname = "www.example.com";
var client = new TcpClient(hostname, 443);
var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
```

After the above completes without throwing an exception, I know the server cert has been validated and the hostname adequately matches the subject.  The subject is accessible via the property `sslStream.RemoteCertificate.Subject` which is a string in DN format, something like

```
CN=www.example.com, O=Example Inc, L=New York, S=New York, C=US
```

or

```
CN=*.example.com, OU=Certificate Authority Validated
```

For esoteric reasons, I want to validate another string (another hostname) against the same cert subject.  How do you correctly validate that a particular hostname matches the subject of a cert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the relevant standard:  [RFC2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).

Of particular importance:  The question asks how to parse the Subject string, and the correct answer is:  In general, you shouldn't do that.  Parsing the Subject string has been deprecated since at least 2000 when RFC2818 was written, in favor of subjectAltName.dNSName.

Here's the mono implementation:  (Search for `checkServerIdentity` in the following file)
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client/TlsServerCertificate.cs

I previously posted this information as an edit to the question, and said it doesn't count as an answer because the code was incomplete - sections of code marked `TODO` and `DEPRECATED`.  But now I have reviewed both the code and the RFC more closely, and found that the `DEPRECATED` comment is required by the RFC standard, and the `TODO` comment has actually been done - just apparently someone forgot to remove the TODO comment.

Comment: Another of your comments suggests you might not be aware of http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ - I can't really tell which class you'd hope to find the .NET CLR implementation in, but if it exists, it should be available there.

Comment: @TomW Thank you for that!  No, I didn't know...  It is important to note the difference of license terms - that particular file in mono is MIT licensed, while the MS reference source is MS-RSL which is more restrictive. Also, apparently you can only step through the .Net Reference Source for certain assemblies - which doesn't include System.Net.Security - and I have not been able to find the relevant section of the MS reference code.

Comment: > Parsing the Subject string has been deprecated since at least 2000 when RFC2818 was written, in favor of subjectAltName.dNSName

I disagree, because SAN is not mandatory, therefore you still have to parse Subject field.

Comment: There's nothing to disagree with.  It's written right in the standard.  Quoted from RFC2818:  "If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead."  Deprecated doesn't mean you don't do it; it means you do something else first (if available) and only use the deprecated method if you have no other choice.

Comment: RFC2818 was written in 2000, so it has long since been safe to assume it's fully adopted and in practice, you'll never encounter a cert that lacks the dNSName, unless you somehow cause it to happen yourself.  So as the standard says, check the dNSName first, and then fall back to parsing the Common Name.  Although it will never happen in practice, it's still what you need to do in order to be standard compliant.

Comment: > "so it has long since been safe to assume it's fully adopted and in practice"


unfortunately, it is not fully adopted yet. I can confirm this with my experience in PKI world. Trust me, PKI is one of the slowest technology in the world. Although, this RFC is written 14 years ago, the reality is different.

Comment: No problem.  Standard is to use dNSName first and then fall back to parse Common Name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate the SSL subject name validation, you will have to do some work, because this process is not very simple. Here is a guidance to implement subject name validation in the certificate:

1. Evaluate X509Certificate2 object's Subject Alternative Names extension. If this extension is not present, then:

1.1. Extract CN attribute from certificate by using the following regex pattern: `'CN=([^,]+)'` and validate it with the desired name. Since CN attribute may contain wildcards, you should verify it by using regex. Here is an example of simple wildcard class.

```
class Wildcard : Regex {
    public Wildcard(String pattern) : base(WildcardToRegex(pattern)) { }
    public Wildcard(String pattern, RegexOptions options) : base(WildcardToRegex(pattern), options) { }
    public static String WildcardToRegex(String pattern) {
        return "^" + Escape(pattern).Replace("\\*", ".*") + "$";
    }
}
```

2. If SAN extension is presented, ignore Subject field validation and use address validation against a collection of DNSName and IPAddress alternative names in a same manner.
3. If step 1 or 2 succeeds, check full certificate chain (up to a root certtificate) for Name Constraints extension end verify:

   3.1. if Name Constraints defines Exclude section, verify whether another name do not match to any entry in the list. Otherwise, the name is not allowed for this certificate (step 3.2 is not performed).

   3.2. if Name Constraints defines Include section, verify whether another name do match to any entry in this section. If another name do not fall to any entry in the Include section, then this name is not allowed for this certificate.

Unfortunately, .NET doesn't have a native class that woul represent a SAN extension, so you will have to write your own decoder or use my own .NET extension library (PKI.Core.dll) from [PowerShell PKI project](http://pspki.codeplex.com/)

The following class represents SAN extension: http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/T_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509SubjectAlternativeNamesExtension.htm

Comment: Thank you, and in fact this answer might be accidentally correct, *but* there's probably a 30-page long standard written somewhere that formally defines the exact format of the Subject.  Behind the scenes, I'm sure they've read that standard and coded accordingly.  I don't have access to the source code behind the scenes (maybe will find the mono source code for this, but haven't found it yet in only a few minutes searching).  Other projects - openssl, bouncycastle, etc, surely have source that's readable... I don't want to invent a new solution here. I want to make sure I get it right.

Comment: This is not very common task. I'm not aware about any API or tools that would check whether the abstract URL (host name) matches subject string outside of connection context. Therefore you will have to either use active connection (like you already do) or implement your own URL->Subject validator.

Comment: I know.  It would be cool if the method used by SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient were exposed for general use - but it's not exposed - so I expect I'll have to recreate it.  It's very easy to do as written in this answer, just write some regex code that parses the string in the way that looks like it makes sense.  But I'd like to be a little more certain that it's done right.  This means either finding an example to follow (MS Source code, mono source, etc) or finding the standard written somewhere, so it can be followed.

Comment: For example, I only mentioned SSL certs for specific hostnames and wildcards.  There also exist SSL certs for multiple hostnames.  How would those be formatted?  I don't know.  But I know the above regex doesn't handle them...  And are there any other possibilities?  I don't know...

Comment: The above regex handles multiple hostname subject. Why? Because more than one instance of CN attribute is not allowed in the Subject field (as per RFC5280). Therefore, if certificate is supposed to be used for multiple names (not wildcard), then all these names must be placed in the Subject Alternative Names extension. The behavior of certificate with SAN is to ignore Subject field. Continue in the next comment.

Comment: That is, Subject field may be empty or contain some entry. Web browser looks only to SAN extension to lookup for applicable names and name matching is performed in the same way as for Subject field (with wildcard support). However, be aware, that '*' character allows multiple names at the same domain level. That is, `DNSName=*.domain.com` is not valid for www.server2.domain.com host name. If you can execute certificate chain, then you can skip name constraints extension processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63536/discussion-between-cryptoguy-and-edward-ned-harvey).